# Need to copy files from one drive to another using batch script but needs to automate source folder as DATA_year

Tags: batch-file

I have a source path (DATA_year) for every year this folder will be created and needs to be copied to destination which would be like Yearyyyy.

Kindly suggest

Comment: You should edit you question and post what did you tried as code so far !

Comment: we need the code manja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I suggest:

```
xcopy {current folder} {destination folder}
```

For the {current folder}, an example could be: `C:\Users\Nidhi\desktop\DATA_year\`

And for the {destination folder}, an example could be:`C:\Users\Nidhi\documents\Yearyyyy\`

This code would transfer all files inside the folder {DATA_year} located on you desktop, to the folder named {Yearyyyy} in your documents section of your PC.

To make this process more efficient, use this code: `xcopy /s {current folder} {destination folder}`

Xcopy is a program installed on all windows pcs and it can be used in this way!

I assume you use Windows...

I hope I could give you the answer you were looking for and happy coding!